# Bolding a keyword if found in a string

Tags: php

```
<?php
$keywords1 = array("stack","stack overflow");
$keywords2 = array("stack overflow","stack");
$str1 = "stack overflow";
$str2 = "stack overflow";
foreach($keywords1 as $kw){
    if (preg_match("~\b$kw\b~i", $str1)) {
        $str1 = str_replace($kw,'<b>'.$kw.'</b>',$str1);
         }
}
foreach($keywords2 as $kw){
    if (preg_match("~\b$kw\b~i", $str2)) {
        $str2 = str_replace($kw,'<b>'.$kw.'</b>',$str2);
         }
}
echo $str1;
echo "<br>";
echo $str2;

?>
```

Greetings, Actually I want to bold a keyword if it is found in a string. I am using php preg_match() method for this purpose. My keywords are stored in an array and by iterating through each keyword I match it with my string and then bold it. I am facing a problem here. Both of the above strings are giving me different outputs.
str1 is giving me **stack** overflow while str2 is giving me **stack overflow**.
But for both cases both of the words should be bold. Please give me the solution to solve this problem.

I have this issue on https://www.paraphraser.site/

Comment: preg_replace("/\w*?$kw\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str1);

Comment: You don't need to iterate the array, just join() it with '|' and use one preg_replace_all() to replace all matches. Something like this: $regex = join('|', $keywords); preg_match_all("/($regex)/i", "<b>$1</b>", $str);

Comment: @Movs it's not working bro!

Comment: @NoumanAli as an idea you can split all your keysords by space symbol before it. You'll get the result like this: "<b>stack</b> <b>overflow</b>". Here is the code: $keys=array();
foreach($keywords as $key){
$keys=explode(" ", $key);
}
$regex = join('|', $keys); 
echo preg_replace("/($regex)/i", "<b>$1</b>", $str);

Comment: @Movs its didn't work again bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below Example code for Reference, you can do as per given examples:

```
preg_replace("/\w*?$kw\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str1)
```

\w*? matches any word characters before the keyword (as least as possible) and \w* any word characters after the keyword.

And I recommend you to use preg_quote to escape the keyword:

```
preg_replace("/\w*?".preg_quote($kw)."\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str1)
```

For Unicode support, use the u flag and \p{L} instead of \w:

```
preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($kw)."\p{L}*/ui", "<b>$0</b>", $str1)
```

For your code you can do it Like below:

```
        $keywords1 = array("stack","stack overflow");
    $keywords2 = array("stack overflow","stack");
    $str1 = "stack overflow";
    $str2 = "stack overflow";
    usort($keywords1, function($a, $b){
    return strlen($a) < strlen($b);
    });
    usort($keywords2, function($a, $b){
    return strlen($a) < strlen($b);
    });
    foreach($keywords1 as $kw){
        if (preg_match("~\b$kw\b~i", $str1)) {
            $str1 = preg_replace("/\b$kw\b/", "<b>$0</b>", $str1);
            // $str1 = str_replace($kw,'<b>'.$kw.'</b>',$str1);
            }
    }
    foreach($keywords2 as $kw){
        if (preg_match("~\b$kw\b~i", $str2)) {
            // $str2 = str_replace($kw,'<b>'.$kw.'</b>',$str2);
            $str2 = preg_replace("/\b$kw\b/", "<b>$0</b>", $str2);
            }
    }
    echo $str1;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $str2;
```

Comment: Check Updated Code, I've added 2 Sorting function for your code, As per your code If String goes to  replace that what happen for first string is: First it will replace "Stack Overflow" to "<b>Stack</b> Overflow" as you have second work in array is "Stack overflow" So After First Replace it will be "<b>Stack</b> Overflow", So Second time It will not match that full word. In your Second loop in First Condition it gets replace Like "StackOverflow" to "<b>Stack Overflow</b>", So in Second time it will be like "<b><b>Stack</b> Overflow</b>"

Comment: like this
**stack** overflow
**stack overflow**

Comment: Have you added following code:  usort($keywords1, function($a, $b){
    return strlen($a) < strlen($b);
    });
    usort($keywords2, function($a, $b){
    return strlen($a) < strlen($b);
    });

Comment: It's Working code of My Local system: http://prntscr.com/240ljlq

Comment: Bro There is an issue I am facing here.
If I give my array like this: 
$keywords = array("stack","work","in","over");
and string like this:
$str = "work in stack overflow over";
its giving output:
**work in stack overflow over**
But my desired output should be:
**work in stack** overflow **over**
Please give me a solution for it.

Comment: Try this: $str1 = preg_replace("/$kw\b/", "<b>$0</b>", $str1);

Comment: I have also updated answer for exact word matching, You just need to change just preg_replace from pattern and then it will work fine, Check my above comment or check update answer

Comment: now if string came like this "work in stack flowover over". It's giving output:
**work in stack** flow**over** **over**. But my desired output should be:
**work in stack** flowover  **over**.

Comment: Can you please check with this? $str1 = preg_replace("/\b$kw\b/", "<b>$0</b>", $str1);

Comment: Thanx buddy it worked Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: 'foreach($prepositionArray as $prep){
                if (preg_match("~\b$prep\b~i", $shortHeadlineString)) {
                    $shortHeadlineString = preg_replace("/\b$prep\b/i", $prep, $shortHeadlineString);
                }
            }' Hello Boss Can You please convert this code into corresponding javascript code please?

Comment: Do you want like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Dhar007/ge4j7b2s/1/

Comment: I want case insensitive searching. What would I have to do for it ?

Comment: Boss I have done the incasesensitive matching. Now I also want to match special characters inside the string from keywords. How would I do it?

Comment: You can share some of String or some of Examples, So We can get Idea

Comment: okay let me share sir!!!

Comment: Using the above mentioned code,
If our array is like this:
$keywords1 = array("stack","stack overflow","{#36bb}");
and string is like this:
$str1 = "stack overflow {#36bb}";
then the resultant output is like this:
**stack overflow** {#36bb}
But my desired output should be like this:
**stack overflow {#36bb}**
According to me its happening because we did not handle the case of special characters. So how would we handle them in our regular expression?

Comment: Please help me in this regard thanks.